# Reshape a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I'm a trying to manage a big data.frame to reshape it. I tried some little things, but as I'm newbie in R, I cannot do it as I wish

```
DF1 <- data.frame(V1 = c("Sample1", "Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample2"),
                  V2 = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene1", "Gene2"), 
                  V3 = c(12, 12, 12, 12))
```

I would like to reshape it as :

```
DF2 <- data.frame(V1 = c("NA", "Gene1", "Gene2"), 
                  V2 = c("Sample1", 12, 12), 
                  V3 = c("Sample2", 12, 12))
```

I tried to dissociate the table in small tab containing all the gene information for 1 sample and after merge them to place the gene in row. But is there a simplest way to do that?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Would something like: `dcast(DF1, Gene~Sample)` work for you?

Comment: Oh yes :D in this example it works with dcast(DF1, V2~V1). Thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: The resulting dataframe is not exactly what you want, but you probably want to have `Sample1` and `Sample2` as column names not as data entries.

In the `tidyverse` spirit, you can solve your problem as following:

   `library(tidyverse); spread(DF1, key = V1, value = V3)`

Welcome to R!

Comment: yap, it could be a solution too. I need to read the vignette of the package to manage some identical values, because it seem to doesn't support them :) thanks